# Twist? on removing items from a list while iterating in python

Tags: python, iteration

I know there are a lot of similar questions regarding this topic and I've researched enough to make me think this twist on the question hasn't been discussed or is just hard to find. I understand you can't just remove items from a list you are iterating unless you use some kind of copy or something. The example I come across time and

```
list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for x in list[:]:
    if x==3:
        list.remove(x)
        list.remove(7)
```

This should remove 3, and 7 from the list. However, what if I have the following:

```
for x in list[:]:
    if x==3:
        list.remove(x)
        list.remove(7)
    if x==7:
        list.remove(9)
```

This iteration removes 3,7, and 9. Since 7 "should" have been removed from a prior iteration, I don't actually want 9 to be removed (since there shouldn't be a 7 in the list anymore). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve which you found this possible solution for?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Well, I'm trying to go through a list of words, and each word object has synonyms associated with it. I want to group the words according to this one algorithm but once I create one group, I don't want see those words(and their associated synonyms) again. In essence, I'd like to partition my results by going through some kind of iteration? Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another check to the if statement:
if x == 7 and x in list:
    list.remove(9)

Comment: Wow that was so simple and it seems to work. It sort of seems to me that those two statements `x==7` and `x in list` are basically the same, but I guess they're not?

Comment: This is because, as Code-Apprentice points out, you are iterating over a copy of the original list.  It might be less confusing to write 
list2 = list[:]
for x in list2:
    #etc

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you are removing from the original list and iterating over a copy. The copy still has the 7 in it, so the 9 will be removed as well.

Comment: So I guess my question is, how would I be able to do what I want? I assume by your answer that copies aren't the way to go, so what is?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for x in list1:
    if x == 3:
        list1.remove(x)
        list1.remove(7)
    if x == 7:
        list1.remove(9)
print list1

Output: [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10]
```

Instead of iterating over a new list, you can work on the same one.